# CakePHP 3.6 number currency

Tags: cakephp

I set

```
I18n::setLocale('en_EN');
```

and

```
I18n::setLocale('de_DE');
```

depending on language switch.

I found that:

```
<?=$this->Number->currency($price, 'EUR', ['precision' => 0])?>
```

shows in german like

> 6.900.000 €

and in english like

> €6,900,000.00

Why the precision is not respected?
Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I don't think `en_EN` is a valid/supported locale, you'd rather use `en_US`, `en_GB`, `en_CA`, etc. Using invalid/unsupported locales are likely to trip the formatter.

That being said, this still looks like a possible bug. Internally CakePHP uses the intl `NumberFormatter`, and it seems that if you want to format a currency that is not the default currency for the given locale (say `EUR` for the `en_US` locale), that currency must be applied as an attribute on the formatter, *before* applying the precision, CakePHP however only passes the currency to the `NumberFormatter::formatCurrency()` method.

You may want to report this as an issue [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues).

See also **http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php#114376**